# UISearchController searching two arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisearchcontroller

How can I use UISearchController to search two different arrays and create two new filtered arrays based on that search? The parameters should only require that one array contain the string, then if one of the arrays have it, both indexes should be added. As of now, I use

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredKeys.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredValues.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (values as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    println(array)
    let arrayTwo = (keys as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)



    filteredKeys = arrayTwo as! [String]
    filteredValues = array  as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, this is very bad and often crashes the app due to a difference in the count of the filtered arrays. Please help, I have been stuck on this for a while.

The search should look at the content:

```
arrayOne = ["title1", "title2", "title3]
arrayTwo = ["message1", "message2", "message3]
```

and should filter the arrays based on the search title1 as

```
arrayOneFiltered = ["title1"]
arrayTwo = ["message1"]
```

Could someone help me with the predicate string and the filtering please?

Again, this is using a UISearchController in a TableViewController

Comment: Instead of maintaining two separate arrays for key and its value, maintain an array of dictionaries. This way, you'll be needing to only manage one array, that's dictionary array.

Comment: @AdilSoomro hwo could I search and filter the dictionary?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dictionary or NSDictionary already provides key-value pair type mechanism, you can wrap your related values in a dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary = ["title_key": "title something", "message_key": "message text"]
```

And then you can make an array of dictionaries.

```
var masterArrayOfDictionaries = [ dictionary , ["title_key": "title something 2", "message_key": "message text 2"]]
```

You can make dictionary at runtime and append to array:

```
var dictionary3 = ["title_key": "title something 3", "message_key": "message text 3"]
masterArrayOfDictionaries.append(dictionary3)
```

Now your predicate should look like:

```
//You want to search on the 'message_key' so put it in the predicate
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "message_key CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
```

Now apply the predicate as follow:

```
let arrayFiltered = (masterArrayOfDictionaries as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

This will give you filtered array having the dictionaries that contains searched text against their `message_key`